# TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not int

Tags: python

Why am I getting this error in the very basic Python script?  What does the error mean?

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cab.py", line 16, in <module>
    if cab in line:
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not int
```

Script:

```
import re
import sys

#loco = sys.argv[1]
cab = 6176
fileZ = open('cabs.txt')
fileZ = list(set(fileZ))

for line in fileZ:
     if cab in line: 
        IPaddr = (line.strip().split())
        print(IPaddr[4])
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You simply need to make `cab` a string:

```
cab = '6176'
```

As the error message states, you cannot do `<int> in <string>`:

```
>>> 1 in '123'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not int
>>>
```

because [integers](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) and [strings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#str) are two totally different things and Python does not embrace implicit type conversion (["Explicit is better than implicit."](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)).

In fact, Python *only* allows you to use the `in` operator with a right operand of type string if the left operand is also of type string:

```
>>> '1' in '123'  # Works!
True
>>>
>>> [] in '123'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not list
>>>
>>> 1.0 in '123'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not float
>>>
>>> {} in '123'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not dict
>>>
```

Comment: That was it.  Simply added the single quotes and it worked.  Thank you.